# How can I solve for a symbolic variable and later evaluate numerically?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to create a worksheet to calculate chemical solution molarity, which is governed by $c_a \times v_a=c_b \times v_b$ ($c_a$ and $c_b$ are initial and final concentrations, whereas $v_a$ and $v_b$ are initial and final volumes). The perfect way to do this would be to (preferably in the following order):

- Take numeric inputs for all 4 variables
- Input the equation, solve algebraically for desired unknown (not always the same!)
- Solve numerically for desired unknown

[This](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html) discusses how to solve algebraically for various unknowns, but unless the preferred strategy is to write $(c_a \times v_a)-(c_b \times v_b)=0$, I don't know how to apply it to my problem. I would prefer not to do that because my manager is unfamiliar with *Mathematica* and it looks kinda ugly.

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you got it right, lookup solving algebraic equations in the documentation and find that `Solve[]` is what to use.

You don't need to solve for 0, just plugin and lets say you're solving for ca

```
Solve[ca * va==cb * vb ,ca]
```

output shows: `{{ca -> cb * vb / va}}`

Then use replace variables with ReplaceAll[] or "/." : *** and then insert all known variables as below***

```
ReplaceAll[% , {cb -> 1, va -> 2, vb -> 3}]
```

output should show : `{{ca -> 3/2}}`